# Trying to set DatePicker template to open in the middle of a page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using [angular-bootstrap-0.5.0](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) andtheir datepicker-popup template for choosing dates in my application.

I am having a problem making the popup window open on the center of the row right beneath the icon I decalred which on click should open it.

This is my template for now:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/popup.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/popup.html",
    "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" ng-style=\"{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', right: position.right+'520px'}\" class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n" +
    "   <li ng-transclude></li>\n" +
    "   <li class=\"divider\"></li>\n" +
    "   <li style=\"padding: 0px;\">\n" +
    "       <span class=\"btn-group\">\n" +
    "           <button class=\"btn btn-small btn-inverse\" ng-click=\"today()\">today</button>\n" +
    "       </span>\n" +
    "       <button class=\"btn btn-small btn-success pull-right\" ng-click=\"isOpen = false\">closed</button>\n" +
    "   </li>\n" +
    "</ul>");
}]);
```

This is the line that is responsible to where the pop-up window will pop:

```
ng-style=\"{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', right: position.right+'520px'}
```

I have tried to add `520px` so it will open in the center but on smaller screens this of course doesn't work correct. also the `top: position.top` is also not that good always. I believe the solution is simple but I am not that good at positioning elements.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show an absolute div in the center of a screen you should first set a static width (in px, em or rem) to your dialog and then use the following css rules :

```
left: 50%;
margin-left : -(dialogWidth/2) px;
width : dialogWidth px;
```

Let say you want to set the width of your dialog to 250px then the above should be :

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px;
width : 250px;
```

Note that the same kind of rules may be applied to top positionining if you set a static height